# Find the number of times a certain value appears in previous rows

Tags: mysql

I have something like this and want the number of transcation done by USER1 up until that moment:

```
USER1 - 12$
USER2 -  9$
USER1 -  8$
USER3 - 18$
USER1 - 34$
```

and I need something like this please:

```
USER1 - 12$ - 1
USER2 -  9$ - 1
USER1 -  8$ - 2
USER3 - 18$ - 2
USER1 - 34$ - 3
```

The last column shows the number of total transactions by the user 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away with SELECT and local variable:

```
SET @a=0;
SELECT yourtable.*, IF(user='USER1',@a:=@a+1,@a) 'user1-transactions' FROM yourtable;
```

Or you can even go as far as not showing the transaction count for rows that aren't for USER1:

```
SET @a=0;
SELECT yourtable.*, IF(user='USER1',@a:=@a+1,NULL) 'user1-transactions' FROM yourtable;
```

Please note that this is depending on the order in which the rows are retrieved from the table. If you add `ORDER BY` to your query, or create an index to the table, you'll change the results.

Comment: great thanks. Folow up auestion if you can: Do you know any alternatives that can be used for views since they don't allow using variables. Thanks